# Jquery offset is not seen in fierfox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the draggable functionality in jQuery. Earlier, I was using jQuery 1.7.3 and jQuery UI 1.10.3.  Then, I had to migrate to jQuery 1.10.1 as some other plugins were  not working with jQuery 1.7.3.

Now, all my plugins are working fine and jQuery Draggable is also working, but when a user tries to drag, it is not showing the offset.  Though, when user drops it, it is getting dropped.

It is working fine in chrome, but it is not working properly on IE8 nor firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to use jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery Ui 1.10.3.

This is well known issue in jQuery. I have also faced this problem. And I used jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery 1.10.3. Maybe it works for you also.